# Extracting multiple subtrings from large string

Tags: java, string, substring

My output file looks like this

```
instance of Win32_Service
{
AcceptPause = FALSE;
AcceptStop = TRUE;
Caption = "Application Experience";
CheckPoint = 0;
CreationClassName = "Win32_Service";
Description = "Processes application compatibility cache requests for applications as they are launched";
DesktopInteract = FALSE;
DisplayName = "Application Experience";
ErrorControl = "Normal";
ExitCode = 0;
Name = "AeLookupSvc";
PathName = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\svchost.exe -k netsvcs";
ProcessId = 1200;
ServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
ServiceType = "Share Process";
Started = TRUE;
StartMode = "Auto";
StartName = "localSystem";
State = "Running";
Status = "OK";
SystemCreationClassName = "Win32_ComputerSystem";
SystemName = "DHARMA-PC";
TagId = 0;
WaitHint = 0;
};

instance of Win32_Service
{
AcceptPause = FALSE;
AcceptStop = FALSE;
Caption = "Application Layer Gateway Service";
CheckPoint = 0;
CreationClassName = "Win32_Service";
Description = "Provides support for 3rd party protocol plug-ins for Internet Connection Sharing";
DesktopInteract = FALSE;
DisplayName = "Application Layer Gateway Service";
ErrorControl = "Normal";
ExitCode = 1077;
Name = "ALG";
PathName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\alg.exe";
ProcessId = 0;
ServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
ServiceType = "Own Process";
Started = FALSE;
StartMode = "Manual";
StartName = "NT AUTHORITY\\LocalService";
State = "Stopped";
Status = "OK";
SystemCreationClassName = "Win32_ComputerSystem";
SystemName = "DHARMA-PC";
TagId = 0;
WaitHint = 0;
};
```

I would like to store the RHS values of each instance of Win32_Service in seperate variables. I have a solution in mind, but I a more efficient can be obtained. For the 24 properties of each Instance I can loop each property, find the IndexOf('=') and IndexOf(';') and obtain the value between them.

Comment: Where is the code that produced this ? And what is your actual question ?

Comment: Why don't you use the `Properties` class?

Comment: These are the contents of a string. I need to store the RHS values in separate variables.